# Can one have cacti and non-cactus plants in the same pot?

Tags: houseplants, planting, cactus, repotting

I have these 3 small cacti which are getting too big for their pot. I was thinking of replanting them together with this larger plant.

- Would that be possible to have cacti and a non-cactus plant together in the same pot?

Thanks. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: btw the clay pot is perfect for the roots. way better then plastic

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a good idea - the cactus needs fast draining soil  mix, and water is very much reduced or even suspended in winter during dormancy. They  also need a position with some evening or morning sunlight. The Dracaena marginata needs watering year round, and just needs ordinary potting soil, as well as medium or bright light conditions, but without direct sunlight. Since their needs are different, it would be better to keep them potted up separately.

Comment: you know the truth is that we are both right and wrong at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

yes ofcourse if they have similar environmental requirements :)

all you need to do is check out the growing environment that both require and if they match then it's all good in the hood :)

you will need a bigger pot to give them both enough space

you have a Dracaena and that plant requires filtered light so not direct sun but the cactus loves full sun so you will need to keep them both happy by giving them moderate amounts of light not too bright and not always in the shade.

if you manage to position them by a window you might be able to control how much more light one will receive by the way you position the pot.

to make this worked there has to be  a compromise and one will always be slightly unhappy

I would personally recommend keeping them separate given they prefer different light amounts.
and water schedules

Comment: Cheeky - you altered your answer after I  posted mine!

Comment: it should be fine but your right about the dormancy period.  in all fairness the Dracaena  will drink up the water at that time but it would have to be tiny amounts of water every time.  it's not worth the stress it's much easier to keep them separate :).

Comment: I clarified my answer  ...as I realised that it might be too difficult to manage in the long run